# Subplot misalignment issue with subfloat and minipage

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage

I'm trying to put together a couple subplots using `minipage` and `subfloat` and I keep getting the following misalignment issue:
[image]

There's clearly enough space in the minipage and I reduced the size of the last two images/increased the size of the minipages just to be sure and no dice. It doesn't happen when I only put six images (three per minipage); could there be some sort of issue with having four per minipage?

This is my code for the plot:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c][17cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[$t_{1}=3$,$t_{2}=0.5$ initial conditions.]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{mode2range3-2_1.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range3-05_1}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=2$,$t_{2}=0.5$ initial conditions.]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{mode2range2-1_1.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range2-05_1}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=4$,$t_{2}=1$ m initial conditions.]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{mode2range4-2_1.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range4-1_1}
}
\subfloat[$t_{1}=4$,$t_{2}=1.5$ m initial conditions.]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{mode2range4-15_1.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range4-15_1}
}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c][17cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[$t_{1}=3$,$t_{2}=0.5$ ISWs.]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{mode2range3-2_2.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range3-05_2}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=2$,$t_{2}=0.5$ ISWs.]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{mode2range2-1_2.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range2-05_2}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=4$,$t_{2}=1$ ISWs.]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{mode2range4-2_2.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range4-1_2}
}
\subfloat[$t_{1}=4$,$t_{2}=1.5$ ISWs.]{%
  \includegraphics[clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{mode2range4-15_2.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range4-15_2}
}
\end{minipage}
\caption{The density profile of the initial conditions (left) and the point where the ISWs reach the right boundary (right) for the cases in which the coefficients for the two thicknesses of the pycnocline have been varied to $t_{1}=3$,$t_{2}=0.5$, $t_{1}=2$,$t_{2}=0.5$, $t_{1}=4$,$t_{2}=1$, and $t_{1}=4$,$t_{2}=1.5$.}
\end{figure}
```

and the packages I'm using:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

What could the issue be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have no paragraph break before the last subfloat in each minipage

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ahh, thank you! Should have known it was something that dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Some off-topics suggestions (main problem is already solved by @David Carlisle comment):

- Move by use of `subcaption` options `belowskip` and `skip` subcation closer to image and away from image below.
- Make `minipage`s narrower and image width equal to `minipage`s width.
- Because all images have equal setting, it is sensible to use leays Gin for them. By this code is much shorter.
- Pairs `$t_1=...$,$t_2=...$,` is better to write as `$t_1...,t_2=...$,` . Beside that code is wee bit shorter and the result is (to my opinion) nicer:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex,
            belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \setkeys{Gin}{clip,width=\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[$t_{1}=3,t_{2}=0.5$ initial conditions.]{%
  \includegraphics{mode2range3-2_1.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range3-05_1}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=2,t_{2}=0.5$ initial conditions.]{%
  \includegraphics{mode2range2-1_1.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range2-05_1}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=4,t_{2}=1$ m initial conditions.]{%
  \includegraphics{mode2range4-2_1.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range4-1_1}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=4,t_{2}=1.5$ m initial conditions.]{%
  \includegraphics{mode2range4-15_1.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range4-15_1}
}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[$t_{1}=3,t_{2}=0.5$ ISWs.]{%
  \includegraphics{mode2range3-2_2.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range3-05_2}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=2,t_{2}=0.5$ ISWs.]{%
  \includegraphics{mode2range2-1_2.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range2-05_2}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=4,t_{2}=1$ ISWs.]{%
  \includegraphics{mode2range4-2_2.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range4-1_2}
}

\subfloat[$t_{1}=4,t_{2}=1.5$ ISWs.]{%
  \includegraphics{mode2range4-15_2.png}%
  \label{fig:mode2range4-15_2}
}
\end{minipage}
\caption{The density profile of the initial conditions (left) and the point where the ISWs reach the right boundary (right) for the cases in which the coefficients for the two thicknesses of the pycnocline have been varied to $t_{1}=3, t_{2}=0.5$, $t_{1}=2, t_{2}=0.5$, $t_{1}=4, t_{2}=1$, and $t_{1}=4, t_{2}=1.5$.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use minipages and it's also not clear why setting them to some height.

Use `\subcaptionbox` (or the `subfigure` environment).

```
\documentclass[titlepage, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

\subcaptionbox
  {$t_{1}=3$, $t_{2}=0.5$ initial conditions.\label{fig:mode2range3-05_1}}
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\subcaptionbox
  {$t_{1}=2$, $t_{2}=0.5$ initial conditions.\label{fig:mode2range2-05_1}}
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}

\subcaptionbox
  {$t_{1}=4$, $t_{2}=1$ m initial conditions.\label{fig:mode2range4-1_1}}
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\subcaptionbox
  {$t_{1}=4$, $t_{2}=1.5$ m initial conditions.\label{fig:mode2range4-15_1}}
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}

\subcaptionbox
  {$t_{1}=3$, $t_{2}=0.5$ ISWs.\label{fig:mode2range3-05_2}}
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\subcaptionbox
  {$t_{1}=2$, $t_{2}=0.5$ ISWs.\label{fig:mode2range2-05_2}}
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}

\subcaptionbox
  {$t_{1}=4$, $t_{2}=1$ ISWs.\label{fig:mode2range4-1_2}}
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\subcaptionbox
  {$t_{1}=4$, $t_{2}=1.5$ ISWs.\label{fig:mode2range4-15_2}}
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{The density profile of the initial conditions (left) and the point 
  where the ISWs reach the right boundary (right) for the cases in which the 
  coefficients for the two thicknesses of the pycnocline have been varied to 
  $t_{1}=3$, $t_{2}=0.5$, $t_{1}=2$, $t_{2}=0.5$, $t_{1}=4$, $t_{2}=1$,
  and $t_{1}=4$, $t_{2}=1.5$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Some points to note:

1. I changed the file names in order to produce a picture; reinstate the correct file names and also remove the `height=3cm` option that I used just to emulate your picture;
2. the `clip` option is redundant unless you specify `viewport`;
3. there should always be a space after a comma;
4. I added a (local) setting of `\parskip` in order to separate rows of images;
5. the `[htp]` option is necessary for such a big float.

[image]